# Who cares about the [roadmap]!

Tags: discussion, tags

Me wonders if we should keep [roadmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roadmap). Either it needs cleaning, or it should just be blacklisted since some use it for maps, and some use it for software planning. The former can be replaced with [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maps) and the latter is likely off-topic.

Comment: It has just 37 questions.  You should be able to clean that up yourself without needing a while cleanup crew.

Comment: I wanted to know what others think before doing the work.

Comment: Well the [tag:map] tag isn't for cartographic maps, it's referring to the data structure, so that's obviously not right.  I don't see why SO would need a tag at all to refer to cartographic maps.

Comment: @Servy post fixed; [tag:maps] would relate to mapping software I suppose, a superset of say [tag:google-maps].

Comment: Read the tag wiki.  That's not what it's for at all.

Comment: Tag wiki for [tag:maps]? How does that conflict with *would relate to mapping software*?