# What is our [roadmap] for burnination?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Discussion of the [roadmap] tag happened as early as [2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251045/6471538), but no decision was apparently made at that time and the proposal was not clearly in favor of burnination. I specifically propose burnination.

The tag wiki for the [roadmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roadmap) tag (currently 39 questions) indicates that it is intended for project management questions, which are largely off-topic on Stack Overflow.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

No, the tag is used for:

- Questions about project management.
- Questions about finding routes using mapping/GIS software API's.
- Questions about Business Process Modeling (BPM) software API's.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Not really. The concept in the tag wiki isn't. For the other uses, there are better tags to use.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, it can refer to project management roadmaps, business process flow roadmaps (in process modeling software), or even literal roadmaps for traveling from Point A to Point B by foot, car, or autogyro.

Comment: Either someone cleaned that up or people have really hard time finding it (I bet the first). Is almost the same number of questions that it has in 2014. Another theory is that those found [tag:project-management] firsts?

Comment: I'm not sure of policy here but isn't there a limit of more than 50 questions (or something) for burniation. A simple retag/untag would seem to be more in order here. 39 questions isn't *that* much.

Comment: @Paulie_D for the extended process yes, small tags like this can be nuked by one or two people if consensus is gathered on meta.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I agree with you and think that's the "spirit of the law".  The "letter of the law" seems to indicate once it's posted on meta you can't do anything to it unless it's approved. "A burninate request is nothing more than a proposal, until moved to step 2 by a moderator. If the proposal does not reach a score of at least 20, a moderator will not feature it [step 2]." and "Do not start removing the tag during the "proposal" or "featuring" phases!"   So per the rules, we're stuck with the whole tag now until it's been featured and voted on. :-)

Comment: I noticed there's another fine tag "milestones" too. Maybe we can make that one our next burnination milestone on the roadmap.

Comment: Seems to be hard to understand that a roadmap is not a map of roads....

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I agree that this is off-topic and the tag should be removed. As per
[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) we can use the <50 posts small procedure:

> If you have authoritative knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help.

- Authoritative knowledge doesn't apply since the tag is off-topic.
- Consider yourself conferred with, assuming I'm somewhat trustworthy. Also the question has 24 score currently, so there should be enough votes for community consensus.
- There are only 29 posts using the tag.

So I'd say go ahead and burninate this, using the usual post reviews, close/delete votes and re-tagging. Poke the merry [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if needed.